# Retrieving anagrams in PHP

Tags: php, dictionary, while-loop, shuffle, anagram

I am trying to create a basic anagram generator in PHP.
The code below works with whole words, i. e. shuffling n times the chars of an input string ($word) and checking each shuffled string in a dictionary.

Whenever a match is found, the anagram is saved in an array ($out).

```
// here I read a text file, line by line, containing all the acceptable words
$dictionary = file('./docs/dictionary.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

//here I collect the word to make the anagram of
$word = mysql_real_escape_string(strtolower($_POST["word"]));
$times = 100;

// here I create an empty array where I can store all the anagrams of $word
$out = array();

for ($k = 0 ; $k < $times; $k++){
$string = str_shuffle($word);
    if (in_array($string, $dictionary)){
        array_push($out, $string);
    }
}
$out = array_unique($out);

// now I print all the anagrams that have been stored in $out

foreach($out as $key => $value){
echo "I have found the anagram ".$value.".";
}
```

This trivial approach works using **all the chars** of the input string.
Now I want to search for **partial** anagrams too, removing randomly some chars from the initial string and matching these partial strings to the words in my dictionary.

I tried to proceed as follows, but I got lost in the process:

```
// here I create an empty array where I can later store the partial anagrams
$outpartial = array();

// Here I check how long the initial input string is
$length = strlen($string);
$num = 1;

// now I remove a char from the initial string in every loop and search for anagrams using the other chars which have been kept

while($num < $length){
    $letters = $length - $num;
    $removed = substr($string,-$num);
    $kept = substr($string,0,$letters);
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < $times; $i++){
        $keptchars = str_shuffle($kept);
        if (in_array($keptchars, $dictionary)){
            array_push($outpartial, $keptchars);
        }
    }
    $outpartial = array_unique($outpartial);
    foreach($outpartial as $k => $v){
        echo "Using the chars ".$kept." - ignoring ".$removed." - I have found the partial anagram ".$v.".";
    }
    $num++;
}
```

This part does not work as planned: the while loop above does not retrieve partial anagrams. It removes one char only from the initial string.

Comment: This looks like a good exercise to learn some test-driven development. Can you share your debugging approaches?

Comment: No code should be calling `mysql_` functions anymore.

Comment: I am aware of this flaw. Thanks.

Comment: `str_shuffle()` will also not ensure that all permutations are produced by calling it within a loop.  This whole technique is fundamentally flawed.  A whole new technique needs to be designed -- Too Broad to answer.

Comment: I know. I just use a number of shuffles ($times) to get some permutations. It is a trivial approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
 **You can try this out as per my example**


function funwithAnagrams($text){
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($text); $i++) {
      for($j = count($text) - 1; $j > $i; $j--) {
          $sortedA = str_split(sort($text[$i]));
          $sortedB = str_split(sort($text[$j]));


          if($sortedA == $sortedB) {
            // splice the array at index $j
              array_splice($text, $j, 1);
          }
      }
  }

return sort($text);
}
```